Format border for GROUPBY function result in Excel?
I use this function to filter data with sales total:
=GROUPBY(Table_G[[#All],[Name]:[Dept]], Table_G[[#All],[Sales]],SUM,3,,,Table_G[Dept]="IT")

How can I set inside and outside borders for the results? Regardless of the number of grouped data rows, the main data sometimes increased another time it decreased.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Provide some test data and expected output to help us understand what you want.

See comment in your previous question

Conditional formatting doesn't support dynamic arrays in that way. You would need to set up a series of rules that look for some expected text on certain rows (such as the word "Total") and then set the applies to range to be larger than the expected largest size of the result.
